# TypeScript + React. Как запретить компилировать приложение при ошибках TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

У меня сейчас ошибки `TS` подсвечиваются в `WebStorm` в открытых файлах
Но приложение в браузере при наличии ошибок не падает

Как запретить компиляцию `React` приложения, если в файлах есть ошибки `TS` ?
Чтобы в браузере и консоли показывалось где ошибки

Мой `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2020",

    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src",
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": ["src/**/*", "declarations.d.ts"]
}
```

п.с. - приложение настраивалось вручную, а НЕ через create-react-app

Comment: Я крайне не рекомендую это делать. Во время разработки может быть довольно удобно пописать какой-то бред для отладки и посмотреть на поведение. Ронять надо именно сборку production-билда, а не dev.

Comment: И вообще, как надо догадаться, как ты его собираешь? Насколько я виду, в приложении, созданном через create-react-app dev-сборка как раз-таки падает при ошибках ts и при ошибках линтера.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я создавал приложение прописывая все конфиги вручную, а не через create-react-app

Comment: Ну так тогда в вопросе должен быть конфиг тайпскриптового лоадера (если это вебпак). Или чего-то ещё, чем ты там всё собираешь.